# Laravel - Vue app : comply with european cookies law?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm working on a laravel-vue app which is going to launch in the United States but european users might visit my webpage, so I have to comply with Cookies europen laws.

My laravel app uses laravel standard cookies set, I Don't not use google analytics or similar.

What am I'm planning to do:

I plan to show the cookie modal with Accept and Decline options, if the user has not accepted cookies I unset all cookies from browser with my unsetAllCookies method, on each page Load, is that enough to not get sued?

Do you know of any npm/composer package that makes this easy to handle?

My functions are the following:

```
onDeclinedCookies()
    {
        this.setCookiesAccepted(true);
        this.unsetAllCookies();
    },

    onAcceptedCookies()
    {
        this.setCookiesAccepted(true);
    },

    unsetAllCookies()
    {
        // retrieve all cookies
        var Cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        // set past expiry to all cookies
        for (var i = 0; i < Cookies.length; i++)
        {
            document.cookie = Cookies[i] + "=; expires="+ new Date(0).toUTCString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "My laravel app uses laravel standard cookies set" Then you likely don't need a cookie policy, as you can fairly easily argue they're "strictly necessary" ones. No one should be able to opt out of CSRF protection cookies, for example.